# VBA and Excel columns

Tags: excel, vba

In the Excel-sheet for the A column write procedure, which with MsgBox function returns the column, A1 drawers from the first address of an empty drawer?

Comment: It is unclear what you want ... can you provide an example, or picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Brettdj, don't forget that with 1 reputation, you are pretty much excluded form posting anything but text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer.  I am trying to help you ask your question.  Do not worry if your English is poor.  If you say enough we can guess what you mean.  One sentence is not enough.

Below I have tried to use short, simple sentences.  I hope you can understand me.  Are my guesses correct?  If not, I hope this helps you write a clearer question.

Is this homework?  A first exercise with Excel?  Have you translated it with a dictionary?  "Drawer" is an English word but there are no drawers in Excel.  Do you mean "cell"?  A1 is a cell.  B5 is a cell.  You put things in a drawer.  You put things in a cell.  This is the sort of mistake English - Xxxxxx dictionaries make.

Create and open a new Excel workbook.  Click `Alt`+`F11`.  On the right at the top you will see a grey area.  On the right at the bottom you will see a white area labelled "Immediate".  Down the left you will see something like:

```
VBAProject (Your excel file)
  Microsoft Excel Objects
    Sheet1 (Sheet1)
    Sheet2 (Sheet2)
    Sheet3 (Sheet3)
    ThisWorkbook
```

If you left-click Sheet1 and then right-click, you will see a menu something like:

```
View Code
View Object
--------------------
VBProject Properties
 :     :
 :     :
```

Click `View Code`.  The grey area will turn white.  Here you can enter code for Sheet 1.  Is this what you mean by "in the Excel-sheet"?

I am not going to put code against Sheet1.  I am going to use a Module.

Go to the Toolbar and click Insert.  In the Menu, click Module.

The window down the left will now look like:

```
VBAProject (Your excel file)
  Microsoft Excel Objects
    Sheet1 (Sheet1)
    Sheet2 (Sheet2)
    Sheet3 (Sheet3)
    ThisWorkbook
  Modules
    Module1
```

"Module1" will be grey because it is selected.

I think you have been asked to: "Find the first empty cell in Row 1 and display its column number with MsgBox."  There are many ways of doing this.  Which is the simpliest?  I do not know.  Here are two ways:

```
Option Explicit

' Both these routines work on the ActiveSheet.  That is, the worksheet
' you can see when you switch to Excel.  If this code had been against
' Sheet1, it would have worked on Sheet 1 even if another sheet had been
' active.

Sub FindFirstEmpty1()

  ' This routine uses Offset. Range("A1").Offset(RowOffset, ColOffset) says
  ' I want to look at the cell which is RowOffset rows down from A1 and
  ' ColOffset columns right from A1. 

  Dim ColOffset As Long

  ColOffset = 0
  Do While True
    If Range("A1").Offset(0, ColOffset).Value = "" Then
      Call MsgBox("The first empty column is " & ColOffset + 1, vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If
    ColOffset = ColOffset + 1
  Loop

End Sub

Sub FindFirstEmpty2()

  ' This routine uses Cells(Row, Column).  The columns are numbered: A=1, B=2,
  ' C=3 and so on.  Cells(Row, Column) lets me look at any cell in the
  ' worksheet.

  Dim ColCrnt As Long

  ColCrnt = 1
  Do While True
    If Cells(1, ColCrnt).Value = "" Then
      Call MsgBox("The first empty column is " & ColCrnt, vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If
    ColCrnt = ColCrnt + 1
  Loop

End Sub
```